# Unable to load decorator from global helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application helper to load decorators (based on the RailsCast about presenters).
However, when I try to load the page, I get this error:

```
wrong constant name {object.class}Decorator
```

This is the helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def decorate(object, klass = nil)
    klass ||= "{object.class}Decorator".constantize
    decorator = klass.new(object, self)
    yield decorator if block_given?
    decorator
  end
end
```

I checked and `object` is filled with class `User` and when I change the line to this it works fine:

```
klass ||= UserDecorator
```

So I guess it could be because the `constantize` method can't relate `UserDecorator` to `apps/decorators/user_decorator.rb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a #

```
klass ||= "#{object.class}Decorator".constantize
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def decorate(object, klass = nil)
    klass ||= "#{object.class}Decorator".constantize
    decorator = klass.new(object, self)
    yield decorator if block_given?
    decorator
  end
end
```

You're missing the `#` for the string interpolation.